# Facing java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while calling webservice in WAS 9

Tags: java, web-services, soap, websphere

I am getting following error while calling webservice. Just to mention It works fine with tomcat while running on eclipse. But getting error while using on websphere application server 9.0. Is there any else I need to take care while running on WAS9.

Here is my piece of code:

```java
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapRequestMessage, Url);
```

Logs :

```
javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.callJAXWSDispatch(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:421)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:192)
at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:163)
at com.service.ClientService.callSoapWebService(ClientService.java:46)
```

Answer (score 0):

After lot of searching and investigating, I found following solution.

Currently, IBM Business Process Manager Advanced, WebSphere Process Server, and WebSphere Enterprise Service Bus do not support the SOAP 1.2 protocol. Please use a supported SOAP protocol such as for example SOAP 1.1.

For SOAP1.1 use this:
soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"